# How do I tell if Ruby 2.0 is copy on write friendly?

Tags: ruby

I'm doing this in my `irb` after installing Ruby 2.0:

```
% irb                                                                                              
2.0.0p247 :001 > GC.respond_to?(:copy_on_write_friendly=)
 => false
```

Why is this returning false? How do I know then that Ruby 2.0 is CoW friendly?

Comment: See the comments on this: http://serverfault.com/questions/354639/unicorn-and-copy-on-write-friendly/354645#354645

Comment: So, if I'm including `GC.respond_to?(:copy_on_write_friendly=) and
  GC.copy_on_write_friendly = true` in my `unicorn.rb`, then I can safely assume the CoW will be exploited? (And that the above line would be pretty much useless for Ruby 2.0?)

Comment: Unless you're using REE, that line of code is pretty much useless.

Comment: Ah. Thanks for the clarification @eugen. Would have definitely accepted your answer. :)

Comment: @BenjaminTan you can copy eugen's comment as an answer, and accept it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently Ruby 2.0 is [copy on write friendly](http://patshaughnessy.net/2012/3/23/why-you-should-be-excited-about-garbage-collection-in-ruby-2-0), but the method ":copy_on_write_friendly" is only available in Ruby Enterprise Edition.  The COW friendliness is a function of the garbage collector, and only one gc is available for ruby 2.0 (correct me if I'm wrong!), there is no need for a configuration option.  If you want to query COW friendliness, you would want to query the version of ruby.